# Retrieving all attribute names of an XML element with xpath on xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I can see how I can retrieve all attribute values:
`xml sel -t -v "//element/@*"`

but I want to get all attribute *names*.
I can get the n'th name by, for example `xml sel -t -v "name(//x:mem/@*[3])"` which returns the 3rd attribute name.
but `xml sel -t -v "name(//x:mem/@*)"` does not work (returns the 1st attribute name only)...

### Is there a way to get *all* attribute names?

Comment: I don't think XPath is able to return a list of strings, so no. You could use an XSLT however, to generate an XML or Text output with the attribute names.

Comment: @ThW If I can return the list of *attribute values*, why wouldn't there be a way to return the list of *attribute names*?

Comment: Attributes are still nodes. So you return a node list. The tool outputs the node contents - the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-t` and `-m` to define a template match and then apply another XPath expression with `-v`.

```
$ xml sel -T -t -m "//mem/@*" -v "name()" -n input.xml
```

when applied to this input XML:

```
<root>
    <mem yes1="1" yes2="2"/>
    <other no="1" no2="2"/>
</root>
```

will print:

```
yes1
yes2
```

That's a "short line on the shell", but it's completely unintelligible. Therefore, I would still prefer kjhughes' XSLT solution. Do not sacrifice understandable code in favour of brevity.

You could write a stylesheet that takes an input parameter from the command line, so that you do not have to change the XSLT code if you'd like to retrieve the attribute names of a different element.

---

As suggested by @npostavs, internally, xmlstarlet makes use of XSLT anyway. You can inspect the XSLT that is generated by replacing `-T` with `-C`:

```
$ xml sel -C -t -m "//mem/@*" -v "name()" -n app.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//mem/@*">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="name()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are many more options to explore, see the [xmlstarlet documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#d0e270).

Comment: Ah, you got it using XPath interface alone!   Very nice.  Separately using the -t and -m and -v switches is a great idea.  Congrats!

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks - still, I'm more the XSLT type of person ;-).

Comment: Thanks @MathiasMüller, I like this solution better than the XSLT one, although I see your point of it being "completely unintelligible". However, as long as I'm writing it interactively on a shell console just to inspect some XML files (and supposedly know what I'm doing) I would rather use this one liner.

Comment: Replace the `-T` with `-C` to convert the xmlstarlet command to (hopefully more understandable) XSLT.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for the hint, good to know! The result is surprising (not the stylesheet I would have written), but it makes clear that xmlstarlet uses XSLT anyway. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**This xmlstarlet command:**

```
xml tr attnames.xsl in.xml
```

**Using this XSLT transform, named attnames.xsl:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And this XML file, named in.xml:**

```
<root att1="one">
  <a att2="two"/>
  <b att3="three">
    <c att4="four"/>
  </b>
</root>
```

**Will produce a list of all attributes found in in.xml:**

```
att1
att2
att3
att4
```

**To select all attributes from the `b` element only, modify the XSLT like this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A bit cumbersome with XSLT... How can I select the XML element for which I want to list all attribute names? I'm not looking for all attributes in an XML, only all attributes of a specific XML element (in my example `//x:mem` but could be any other xpath expression)

Comment: @AmirGonnen There's nothing cumbersome about it. If you need a more specific answer, please show your input XML. Saying you want `//x:mem` is not enough. Otherwise, you should accept this answer.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I'm waiting to see if someone suggests a more elegant solution, otherwise I will accept this answer. And it **is** cumbersome. Instead of a short line on the shell (for obtaining attr values) I'll need an accompanied xslt script that I need to edit if I want other element. You know what, why not just write a small perl script or a c++ application to do it? If we have to carry around an accompanied piece of code, let's go the whole way.

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasMüller.  Amir, sorry, but I don't see a way to make it work via xmlstarlet's XPath 1.0 interface alone.   If xmlstarlet implemented XPath 2.0, or if you could use host language iteration facilities combined with XPath 1.0, then I see how XPath 1.0 would suffice.  I'm not saying it's impossible, but I crossed the threshold where dropping into XSLT, which I believe xmlstarlet uses behind the scenes anyway, became the most expedient way to make it work for you.

Comment: @AmirGonnen There _is_ an xmlstarlet solution, but there's no way to guess what it does, in my opinion.